# Castle Windsor configuration based on build or config file

Tags: c#, configuration, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am using Castle Windsor in my own implementation of the Resolver Pattern. I have two implementations of a service `MethodAService` and `MethodBService` that both implement `IMethodService`. I am using "Convention Over Configuration" when bootstrapping Windsor in. How can I tell Castle Windsor to use always use `MethodAService` in one instance (Debug, Release, etc.), but in the other, use `MethodBService`. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Question added to the Windsor FAQ: http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/FAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using `IHandlerSelector`:

```
public class DebugHandlerSelector: IHandlerSelector {
    private readonly Type serviceType;
    private readonly Type debugImplementation;
    private readonly Type releaseImplementation;

    public DebugHandlerSelector(Type serviceType, Type debugImplementation, Type releaseImplementation) {
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
        this.debugImplementation = debugImplementation;
        this.releaseImplementation = releaseImplementation;
    }

    public bool HasOpinionAbout(string key, Type service) {
        return service == serviceType;
    }

    public IHandler SelectHandler(string key, Type service, IHandler[] handlers) {
        return handlers.First(h => h.ComponentModel.Implementation == 
#if DEBUG
            debugImplementation
#else
            releaseImplementation
#endif                    
            );
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
container.Kernel.AddHandlerSelector(new DebugHandlerSelector(typeof(IMethodService), typeof(MethodAService), typeof(MethodBService)));
```

Comment: How do I make this not dependent on IHandlerSelector?

Comment: Or on Castle Windsor for that matter?

Comment: I actually now really like this. I refactored it to use Generics instead of the 3 typeof's in the constructor call!